# Performance and limitations of temporary queues

Tags: jms, hornetq, mom, apollo

I want a bunch of several hundred client apps to create and use temporary queues at one instance of the middleware.

Are there some cons regarding performance why I shouldn't use temp queues? Are there limitations, for example on how many temp. queues can be created per HornetQ instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a recent project we have switched from using temporary queues to using static queues on SonicMQ. We had implemented synchronous service calls over JMS where the response of each call would be delivered on a dedicated temporary queue, created by the consumer. During stress testing we noticed that the overhead of temporary queue creation and allocated resources started to play a bigger and bigger part when pushing the maximum throughput of the solution.

We changed the solution so it would use static queues between consumer and provider and use a selector to correlate on the JMSCorrelationID. This resulted in better throughput in our case. If you are planning on each time (re)creating the temporary queues that your client applications will use, it could start to impact performance when higher throughput rates are needed.

Note that selector performance can also start to play when the number of messages in a queue increase. In our case the solution was designed to hand-off the messages as soon as possible and not play the role of a (storage) buffer in between consumer and provider. As such the number of message inside a queue would always be low.